# CloudFormation template AutoScalingGroup availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

Hi I would like to get all my servers in one availability zone, namely us-west-1a.  How can I specify this with an autoscalinggroup?

```
  "MyFixedSizeGroup":{
    "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
    "Properties":{
        "LaunchConfigurationName":{"Ref":"GlobalWorkersSmallLaunchConf"},
        "AvailabilityZones" :["us-west-1a"],
        "MinSize":"3",
        "MaxSize":"3",
        "DesiredCapacity":"3",
        "Tags":[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"Neo4j Instance", "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"}],
         "NotificationConfiguration" : {
      "TopicARN" : { "Ref" : "NotificationTopic" },
      "NotificationTypes" : [ "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH","autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR","autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE", "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR"]          
    }
  }           
},
```

Currently I am getting errors where `The availability zone [us-west-1a] is not legal`  Thanks!

Comment: Try giving "AvailabilityZones" :"us-west-1a"

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly.

Chances are your account does not have access to that specific zone. You can check this by trying to launch an instance from the EC2 console manually and see if it lets you select that zone.

Otherwise, changes are the availability zone does not have the instance type you have specified in the LaunchConfiguration. You can check this also like above.